# Floating-point exception from fraction simplification program in C

Tags: c, floating-point

When I run the following code, I always get a floating-point exception.  How can I fix it?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    //Global Variables

    int num, denom, num1, denom1;

    void simplify(int *numerator, int *denominator);

    int main () {

    //Prompt User as to what program is
    printf("Fraction Simplifier\n");
    printf("===================\n");

    //Ask User for Numerator and Denominator
    printf("Numerator: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Denominator: ");
    scanf("%d", &denom);

    //Call Function
    simplify(&num1, &denom1);

    //Display final output
    printf("%d / %d = %d / %d", num, denom, num1, denom1);

    return 0;
    }

    //Simplify function
    void simplify(int *numerator, int *denominator)
    {

    num = num1;
    denom = denom1;

    num1 = num1 / num1;
    denom1 = denom1 / num1;
    num1 = *numerator;
    denom1 = *denominator;

    }
```

Comment: You seem to be dividing by `num1`, which is 0 at that time back from when it was defined globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if `num1` is never initialized.  It will be zero, which will result in a division by zero.

Comment: Not only likely. Since it's declared at file scope, it has static storage duration and must be initialised to 0 without explicit initialisation.

Comment: I changed it so that Num1 = 1 and now i get an output, but it is radically wrong for example this is for 1 / 2, 1 / 2 = -1217269772 / 134514089

Answer (score 0):

Your `simplify` function is flawed. Here's what it means when you are calling `simplify`:

> call simplify, passing the address of num1 and denom1

And here's what your code inside of simplify means:

```
num = num1;          /* Assign the value of num1 to num, meaning set num to 0. */
denom = denom1;      /* Assign the value of denom1 to denom, meaning set denom to 0. */
num1 = num1 / num1;  /* Divide num1 (which is 0) by num1 (which is 0). Error! */
```

You can simplify your program and make it easier to understand by eliminating your global variables. This will also help you to correct your errors. Here's a rewrite:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void simplify(int numerator, int denominator, int* newNumerator, int* newDenominator);

int main () {

    int num, denom, num1, denom1;

    /* Do your input code */

    //Call Function
    simplify(num, denom, &num1, &denom1);

    //Display final output
    printf("%d / %d = %d / %d", num, denom, num1, denom1);

    return 0;
}

//Simplify function
void simplify(int numerator, int denominator, int* newNumerator, int* newDenominator)
{
    int simplifiedNumerator;
    int simplifiedDenominator;

    /* Calculate your results.. left out your original code, which calculates incorrectly */
    /* You will refer to the ints numerator and denominator */

    /* Assign your results */
    *newNumerator = simplifiedNumerator;
    *newDenominator = simplifiedDenominator;
}
```

Notice that `simplify` now has four parameters. The first two are the values you want to use in the calculation (we don't need pointers), and the pointers are only used to assign the results to the addresses passed in.